# Changing label for input with CSS in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I would like to change the css of  all labels for all inputs that are disabled. I currently use this in a global scss style sheet:

```
  ::ng-deep input:disabled+label {
    color: rgb(223, 107, 107) !important;
  }
```

```
<label for="someLabel">someLabel</label>
<input id="someLabel" disabled>
```

But the css is not applied to the label.

Comment: Because it's work if `label` right after `input` not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector to find previous selector like below:

```
label:has(+ input:disabled) {
   color: rgb(223, 107, 107);
}
```

Comment: why use `::ng-deep`? why use `!important`?

Comment: @Eliseo I have update my answer, I have tried to follow OP code, but yes it's bad practice to use selector with `important` style.

Comment: sorry i'm a bit angry today, sorry for my rude comment

Comment: @Eliseo It's ok. I can understand. :)

Comment: Note that Firefox does not currently support `:has()`

Answer (score 2):

The `+` plus sign is used to select the elements that are placed **immediately after** the specified element. Therefore your CSS is looking for a `label` tag after a disabled `input` tag.

You can achieve more or less the same result like that:

```css
input:disabled + label {
  color: rgb(223, 107, 107) !important;
}


.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <input id="someLabel" disabled />
  <label for="someLabel">someLabel</label>
</div>
```